# How can a Laravel 4 class detect that it is running in an Artisan task vs. a browser request?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have some application boot code that needs to know if it is currently running in an artisan task vs. being called in a browser request.

How do I detect this in Laravel 4?

Comment: Is such "Artisan task" related to command line? If so, check that `PHP_SAPI == 'cli'`.

Comment: What class? Model, Controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the best way to do it :)

```
    if (App::runningInConsole())
      echo "Running in artisan/CLI";
    else 
      echo "Running in a browser";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answer - it saved me tones of try'n'error :)

Comment: Any idea how to do this in 5.2?

Comment: In laravel 5.2 you can do this with `app()->environment();`

Answer (score 1):

`runningInConsole()` also returns `true` when unit tests are running, then I think a better way to detect if your app is running **only** through artisan is:

```
if (App::runningInConsole() && !App::runningUnitTests()) {
    // ... code to execute when artisan is running.
}
```