# Laravel Vagrant run artisan command in PHP CLI

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, command-line-interface, php-7

I am using Laravel 5.4 with Homestead vagrant and running my app on vagrant where i run tests like `vagrant@homestead:~/ticketApp$ php artisan dusk` and it works fine.
currently i need to apply a hack where i put a check in my code that

```
if ('cli' === PHP_SAPI) {
   // do something
}
```

and run the command php `php artisan dusk` but the condition `'cli' === PHP_SAPI` didn't return `true`
and when i print the `PHP_SAPI` it returns the `fpm-cgi`.

whereas i was expecting that `PHP_SAPI` will return `cli`.

Please help how i'll run my tests to make this condition true

Answer (score 0):

Try run command

```
php-cli artisan dusk
```

Comment: I got this errror:
`No command 'php-cli' found, did you mean:
 Command 'php-cgi' from package 'php7.0-cgi' (main)
php-cli: command not found`

Comment: Ok, check documentation for you Laravel version, modern frameworks implements build-in functional for check request type, example:

`if (App::runningInConsole())
      echo "Running in artisan/CLI";
    else 
      echo "Running in a browser";`
from here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697363/how-can-a-laravel-4-class-detect-that-it-is-running-in-an-artisan-task-vs-a-bro]

Comment: Codegniter do it like this:
`public function is_cli_request()
 {
  return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN'));
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, check documentation for you Laravel version, modern frameworks implements build-in functional for check request type, example:

```
if (App::runningInConsole())
      echo "Running in artisan/CLI";
    else 
      echo "Running in a browser";
```

from here [How can a Laravel 4 class detect that it is running in an Artisan task vs. a browser request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697363/how-can-a-laravel-4-class-detect-that-it-is-running-in-an-artisan-task-vs-a-bro)